# Correct way to display as rows dynamically in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have created a small app to fetch the details of a student given the student id. I am using a table layout for the summary page. I have created a store to collect the mark details of the student.

The page looks like this

http://www.sencha.com/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=48225&d=1394475571

I would like to get some pointer on how to display each marks row by row under the Mark List section. Should I be using an iterate logic or use something like grid (without header) to show the marks.

My Panel looks like this

```
    Ext.define('App.view.DetailsPanel', {
    extend : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.detailspanel',
    layout : {
        type : 'table',
        // The total column count must be specified here
        columns : 2,
        tableAttrs : {
            style : {
                width : '100%',
                height : '60%',
            }
        }
    },
    defaults : {
        // applied to each contained panel
        bodyStyle : 'padding:20px'
    },
    items : [ {
        html : '<b>Student Details</b>',
        border : false
    }, {
        html : 'Age'
    }, {
        html : 'Address'
    }, {
        html : 'Course Details',
    }, {
        html : 'Start Date'
    }, {
        html : 'End Date'
    }, {
        html : 'Mark List',
        height : 60,
        rowspan : 2
        //Would like to have the iteratiion logic to dispay the details row by row in the MarkList store
    }, {
        html : 'Certifications'
    }, {
        html : 'Specialization'
    } ]
});
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would check out using an XTemplate: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate

I would use it not only for the "mark list", but for the entire content as well. It will be more performant, as you are currently creating a container for every single section of your page. Just using HTML without all the Ext JS wrapping might be a better approach.